# Linearization of a 2-D P Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am given the following nonlinear Poisson-Boltzmann equation and asked to derive a linearized form for a current approximation of $u$:
$$ (-\Delta u)\,+k^2\sinh(u) = \rho(x)  $$ 
$$ x \in \Omega, \quad u_{\partial\mkern2mu \Omega} = g $$

For the 1D case I am given $ k = 1, \rho = 0 $ and the exact solution is:
$$ \bar u(s) = \frac{\ln(1+\cos(s))}{\ln(1-\cos(s))} $$

Now for the 2D problem I am told $ k =1, \quad \Omega(0,1)^2 $
The exact solution is:
$$ u(x) = \bar u(0.1 + (x,a)) $$
Where: $$ a = \frac{(1.0,2.0)}{\sqrt5} $$
I need to find $ g, \rho$ such that the exact solution of $ u(x) $ is satisfied.
This is pretty foreign to me considering I am an engineer and don't deal with nonlinear equations of this type. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need this linearization for a project.

Comment: To find the linearised PDE, why not just take the series expansion of $\sinh(u)$ to leading order? Then your problem becomes $$- \Delta u + k^{2} u = \rho$$ which is the [inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Inhomogeneous_Helmholtz_equation). Also, I don't think the discrete mathematics tag applies here.

Comment: Ok then the equation just becomes $$ (-\Delta u)\,+ u = \rho(x)  $$ since $ k =1$. How would I then go about finding the necessary $ \rho $ and boundary condition $ g $ to fit the exact solution given? I'm assuming I have to plug in $ (.1 + (x,a)) $ for $ s $ from the 1D case? The $ (x,a) $ is also tripping me up. Sorry for all the questions, I've haven't dealt with this level of math and notation before.

Comment: You've left out a bit of information in your question. What is $s$? What is $\bar{u}$? What is $\Omega$ in the 1D case? What does $(.1 + (x,a))$ mean? Also, if you are given the solution, just differentiate it and substitute it into the PDE. From this you should be able to derive the form of $\rho$ and the boundary conditions.